# My vb.net program for Excel won't run on different computer

Tags: vb.net, excel

I wrote a vb.net program using Visual Studio 2010 Express to open and manipulate an Excel workbook. I have MS Office 2010 and my program works fine on my computer. When I try to run it on my wife's computer... nothing. I get no error messages... nothing. She has the same version of Office as I do, but she has Windows XP and I have Vista and her computer is has more security protocols than mine, but my other program, which does not import any Office namespaces, runs fine on her computer.

When I look at the task manager on her computer there is nothing under the Applications tab, but under the Processes tab I see an instance of Excel.exe, and if I try to run the program again, still nothing under applications, but yet another instance of Excel.exe under processes.

I have tried to install my program using the Click-Once technology and just the Release folder after a Rebuild... nothing.

I have also tried to compile it under versions 2.0, 3.0, etc.... nothing.

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
Public Class CleanUpDataForm
    Dim m_objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim m_rngRange, m_rngEnd As Excel.Range
    Dim m_blnEntireRow, m_blnCancel As Boolean
    Dim m_strRange, m_strSearch, m_strLogFrameCode As String
    Const c_strCode As String = "log"
    Friend Const c_intScrollBarWidth As Integer = 30

Private Sub CleanUpDataForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As    System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    m_objExcel = Nothing
    Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub tsbOpen_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsbOpen.Click

    ofdGetWorksheet.Title = "Select Worksheet"
    ofdGetWorksheet.Filter = "All Excel Files (*.xl*)|*.xl*|(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|(*.xlsm)|*.xlsm|(*.xlsb)|*.xlsb|(*.xlam)|*.xlam|(*.xltx)|*.xltx|(*.xltm)|*.xltm|(*.xls)|*.xls|(*.xla)|*.xla|(*.xlt)|*.xlt|(*.xlm)|*.xlm|(*.xlw)|*.xlw"
    ofdGetWorksheet.FileName = ""
    If ofdGetWorksheet.ShowDialog <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Me.Text = ofdGetWorksheet.FileName
        m_objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Me.Text)
        tsbCopySheet.Enabled = True
        tsbFindRows.Enabled = True
        tsbClose.Enabled = True
        m_objExcel.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.Text = ""
    End If

    Me.Activate()

End Sub
```

Any ideas??

Comment: This is impossible to guide or troubleshoot without seeing your code.

Comment: Sounds like a DLL could be missing, but as Jusin Satyr said, we can't help you if you don't provide your code...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I was having this issue as well, but this line of code (after your m_objExcel.visible statement) was what fixed it (going from memory).

```
m_objExcel.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

One thing you may want to look at is the Marshal.BindToMoniker method in the InteropServices library.  I found this incredibly useful.  If the file is not open, then it opens it.  If it is open already, then it will use that instance.  Like this...

```
wb = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(fileName) 'open the file.  If the file is already open, then this uses the open file instead of trying to open again
exApp = wb.Parent
```

wb is my workbook variable, exApp is my Excel variable.

One other thing; to make sure Excel is closed and to remove those pesky processes from Task Manager

```
Private Sub KillExcel()
    For Each RunningProcess In Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")
        RunningProcess.Kill()
    Next
End Sub
```